# Don` t see (linked) Qt classes in Doxygen

Tags: qt, doxygen

This is a follow up of [doxygen generated documentation with auto-generated links to qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244779/doxygen-generated-documentation-with-auto-generated-links-to-qt-project) ,
also covered in the Blog [here](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/08/13/qt-weekly-17-linking-qt-classes-in-documentation-generated-with-doxygen/)

Added tagfiles:

```
TAGFILES = qtcore.tags=http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ qtgui.tags=http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ \
           qtwidgets.tags=http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ qtxml.tags=http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ \
           qtnetwork.tags=http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/
```

`GENERATE_TAGFILE = mytags`

Crosscheck, as an example this here works: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore.tags

Nevertheless I do not see any links for Qt classes (I would d expect `QString` to be a link)

[image: No link for QString/Qobject]

What am I doing wrong? Btw, would something like `\copydoc QString::toInt` work then?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the location of your `.tags` files?

A `.tags` file is like an index mapping symbols to documentation relative links. This is why you specify both the **path to the tagfile** and the **actual documentation URL** where symbols are documented (which, by the way, can also be a local path to Qt's docs).

In other words you should specify:

```
TAGFILES = path/to/a/tags/file=URL
```

You can find these `.tags` files inside Qt directory (usually in `QT_DIR/doc/html`).

It may be a good idea to copy them inside your project directory in order to avoid using an absolute path. So if you have the following project structure:

```
myproject/
    Doxyfile
    src/
    doc/
        html/
        qt/
            qt.tags
```

Then your Doxyfile should contain:

```
TAGFILES = doc/qt/qt.tags=http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/
```

All the references to Qt symbols inside your docs will be then linked in the html output generated by Doxygen.

---

Also, the GENERATE_TAGFILE tag is only useful if you want to link to your docs from another project.